# how would I take detect subtitles from a video and copy them into a text area

Tags: javascript, html, video, text

So im creating a chrome extension which takes the subtitles from a video, and copies them into a text area, at the moment I can detect if there is a video playing on the webpage, and if there is one playing, I want the subtitles or the spoken words from the video to be copied into the text area in the extension. Here is the code in javascript

```
Object.defineProperty(HTMLMediaElement.prototype, 'playing', {
get: function(){
    return !!(this.currentTime > 0 && !this.paused && !this.ended && this.readyState > 2);
    }
})

if(document.querySelector('video').playing){ 

    //copy the subtitles into a new variable

}
```

I have also got the text area that the subtitles will be copied into, here is that code in html

```
<textarea rows = "10" cols = "80" id = "text"></textarea>    
    <br>
```

So I want to copy the suptitles from lets say a youtube video, this would then be taken to the text area and be displayed in there. If anyone could help me out that would be great, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are probably going to need to use the "textTracks" property of the HTML5 `<video>` element.

`videoEl.textTracks` will return a *TextTrackList* of all the included tracks (subtitles/captions). You can check the length of the *TextTrackList* to see if there are any tracks and loop through all of them until you find the one with the `language` property matching what you are looking for (example: "en-US"). You should probably also check the `kind` property to make sure it's `"subtitles"` or `"caption"`.

For my example I am just going to use the 0-index textTrack (the first one in the list):

```
var allText = [];
var trackCues = document.querySelector('video').textTracks[0].cues;
var i;

for (i = 0; i < trackCues.length; i += 1) {
  allText.push(trackCues[i].text);
}

document.getElementById('text').innerText = allText.join('\n');
```

Explanation:

We get the *TextTrackList* from the `<video>` element. We select the first available *TextTrack* and get the *CueList* with `.cues`. We then iterate through all "cues" (text slides) in the *CueList* and append the text for them to an array. After we get all of the text we add it to the `<textarea>` element with each entry separated by a line break.

This has very little documentation and it is hard to build a working demo because I would need a subtitle file hosted on the same origin domain as the jsfiddle/codepen/"stack snippet" but I tested it in the console window on some websites that contained subtitled html5 videos and it seems to work (at least on Chrome). It should support as far back as IE10.

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_texttracks.asp

Comment: just checked to see if this works, It doesn't seem to be working, is this because the text area is in another file called popup.html?? Im not sure.

Comment: As long as your textarea and the video are on the same page it should work. You could try `console.log`-ing `allText.join('\n');` to see if you're getting anything. This DOES require that the subtitles of the video be in track elements, and not baked into the video itself.

Comment: If this still isn't working for you let me know what changed you need and I'll try to edit it to accommodate.